# How many samples of two classes can be drawn from this population of five classes?

Tags: r, sample-data

I want to find all the possible samples of two classes from the 5 different classes.
I am trying this:

```
x <- c(A = 23, B = 21, C = 29, D = 17, E = 18)

mean (x)

sd (x)

sample(x)

sample(x, 2, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)

sample(x, 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

but I think it is wrong it does not give me the number of all the possible samples

Comment: What is the result you desire?

Comment: i want to find the code for the r studio... I need to find the right order about how can i have all the possible samples of two classes from my population of 5 classes.

Comment: `choose(5, 2)`? Also, Rstudio is IDE. It's not a programming language.

Comment: why the result is 10?? i can see without knowing the right order that when you have 5 different classes the  possible matches of 2 classes can be more than 10 for sure

Comment: You need to decide if you wan permutations or combinations

Comment: i need permulations of two classes

Comment: Then probably something like `library(combinat) ; permn(x)`

Comment: library(combinat) ; permn(x)
Error in library(combinat) : there is no package called ‘combinat’
>

Comment: try installing it: `install.packages("combinat")`

Comment: install.packages("combinat") ...

Comment: and how can i find the mean of every different combination??

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)
permutations(length(x), 2, x)
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]   17   18
#  [2,]   17   21
#  [3,]   17   23
#  [4,]   17   29
#  [5,]   18   17
#  [6,]   18   21
#  [7,]   18   23
#  [8,]   18   29
#  [9,]   21   17
# [10,]   21   18
# [11,]   21   23
# [12,]   21   29
# [13,]   23   17
# [14,]   23   18
# [15,]   23   21
# [16,]   23   29
# [17,]   29   17
# [18,]   29   18
# [19,]   29   21
# [20,]   29   23
```

If you just want to know the amount of possible permutations go with [@Floo0s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27902278/3001626) or do something like

```
nrow(permutations(length(x), 2, x))
# [1] 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5 classes. There are 5 over 2 possibilities.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

In R this is what the function `choose` calculates.

So

```
choose(length(x),2)
```

Answer: 10 possible combinations (if the order does not matter, so (A,B) is equal to (B,A))

If the order matters it is

```
choose(length(x),2) * factorial(2)
```

Answer: 20

As **Colonel Beauvel** mentioned. To find all these combinations use `combn`

Comment: i think they are more that ten possible matches as we have 5 classes :/

Comment: added a coment about the order. maybe this confuses you

Comment: im looking for the code. i just tried with the sample as order but it doesnt work

Comment: you are looking for what code?

`choose(5,2)` is the same as `factorial(5)/(factorial(2)*factorial(5-2))` as explained in the wikipedia link i posted above

Comment: i want to find the order that will give me all the possible samples of two different classes that can be drawn from the population of 5 classes

Comment: I like that solution (+1) (never heard of `factorial` before).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using:

```
combn(x, 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   23   23   23   23   21   21   21   29   29    17
[2,]   21   29   17   18   29   17   18   17   18    18
```

Columns of the matrix will give you all possible combinations **ignoring order**.

Or use package `combinat`.

Comment: i think they are more that ten possible matches as we have 5 classes :/

Comment: If you want permutations, in this case just do `cbind(combn(x,2),combn(x,2)[2:1,])`

Comment: Compute the binomial coefficient yourself to see there are 10 choice of 2 elements among 5 elements ignoring order ;)

Comment: cbind(combn(x,2),combn(x,2)[2:1,])
i think this fits my need thank you so much